# How am I able to subtract a certain amount from a label

Tags: c#

```
private void battleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (battleDropBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Rat")
     {
            enemyHP.Text = "Enemy HP: " + rat.HP.ToString();
            enemyDPS.Text = "Enemy DPS: " + rat.Damage.ToString();


            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Start();
     }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dealDamage();
}

public void dealDamage()
{
    rat.HP--;
    enemyHP.Text = "Enemy HP: " + rat.HP.ToString();
}
```

I have:

```
rat.HP--;
enemyHP.Text = "Enemy HP: " + rat.HP.ToString();
```

but how can I make it so it will subtract an amount which varies.

Answer (score 3):

Overload the method:

```
public void dealDamage(int damage)
{
    rat.HP -= damage;
    enemyHP.Text = "Enemy HP: " + rat.HP.ToString();
}
```

This way you can either call `dealDamage()` (without parameters) and just decrement `HP` by one, or you can call `dealDamage(yourValue)` to decrement `HP` by a variable amount (i.e. `dealDamage(15)` to decrement `HP` by 15).

To call this from your tick event, if you want a *random* amount of damage between two ranges, you could do the following:

```
void dealRandomDamage(int bottomLimit, int upperLimit) 
{
    dealDamage((new Random()).Next(bottomLimit, upperLimit));
}
```

And then in your tick handler, you could do something like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dealRandomDamage(1, 10);
}
```

To decrement randomly any value between 1 and 10.

**EDIT**: Adam brings up a good point.  If you do take this route, then it would be a good idea to change the `dealDamage()` function definition to the following:

```
public void dealDamage()
{
    dealDamage(1);
}
```

This would eliminate the redundancy and duplication of damage-incurring code (no pun intended).  This way, if you ever changed the logic of *how* damage is dealt then it would only be a single change to logic.

Comment: If you were going to keep `dealDamage()` (with no parameter), I would personally rewrite it to call `dealDamage(1)`, just so you don't have to keep two methods in sync, but still, I like this answer.